# Delete all logfiles from system

Tags: find

I need to delete all the log files older than one month from a Linux server. However the query below does not work:

```
find -type f -name "*.log" -exec rm *.log {} \;
```

and I don't know how to specify "older than one month".

Comment: I can't see any age checking in your find options. And then you should specify what "not working" means. What does it do?

Comment: Also you need to remove that insidious `*.log` from the -exec.

Comment: When you have a "I don't know how to specify.." situation you should seriously consider reading the man page. `man find`.

Comment: i know how to use find but at very basic level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified any time argument in your command.  Also, you should not use `-exec` when the find command provides a handy `-delete` argument.

This should do the job:

```
find / -type f -name "*.log" -mtime +30 -delete
```